# Classe PHP - Como usar

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Como usar uma classe especifica em php ?

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
class Torrent
{
    public function scrape(array $announce = [ ] , $hash_info = null)
    {

        $r = [
            'seeders'  => 0 ,
            'leechers' => 0
        ];

        foreach ( $announce as $an ) {

            $d = get_remote_peers($an , $hash_info);

            if ( isset($d['seeders']) ) {
                $r['seeders'] += $d['seeders'];
            }

            if ( isset($d['leechers']) ) {
                $r['leechers'] += $d['leechers'];
            }
        }

        return $r;
    }

}
?>
```

Como faço para usar essa classe ?

Fiz testes assim:

```
<?php

$meuObjeto = new Torrent();

$meuObjeto->scrape("$r"); 

?>
```

e assim

```
<?php

$meuObjeto = new Torrent();

$meuObjeto->scrape("udp://fopen.demonii.com", 7C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530ADFB8DF6E); 

?>
```

sem sucesso...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530'
>   (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamepatch\udpscrap.php on line 457

Comment: Coloca 7C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530ADFB8DF6E entre aspas, pois é uma string!

Comment: Acredito que a frase `Parse error: syntax error` no começo do erro deva significar alguma coisa...

Answer (score 4):

Observando seu código pude perceber o seguinte erro na linha 3 deste código

```
<?php
$meuObjeto = new Torrent();
$meuObjeto->scrape("udp://fopen.demonii.com", 7C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530ADFB8DF6E); 
?>
```

O segundo parâmetro do metodo `scape()` precisa de aspas (simples ou duplas, tanto faz) para que o formato deste parametro se torne [string](/questions/tagged/string).
Sendo assim ele deveria ficar assim:

```
<?php
$meuObjeto = new Torrent();
$meuObjeto->scrape("udp://fopen.demonii.com", "7C90CFEE93DE8C4FA04526DAA5CE530ADFB8DF6E"); 
?>
```